# Mod_rewrite: Direct everything to one PHP file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?req=$1
</IfModule>
```

Everything works fine if I request non-existing directories like `myhost/view/blah`, but when i enter some existing directory in the url like `myhost/module` I get redirected to `module/?req=module` instead of staying at `module/`

What am I doing wrong?
I would need something that redirects everything to index.php (except index.php, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html) could cause this behavior. Try to disable it.